# PostgreSQL's Foreign Data Wrapper in Amazon Aurora Connection Issues with Two Databases

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-aurora, foreign-data-wrapper

I have created two PostgreSQL databases in Amazon Aurora, let's name them Database A and Database B.

I also managed to set up Foreign Data Wrapper successfully in Database A using psql:
1. Load the extension postgres_fdw
2. Create a foreign server 
3. Create a user mapping
4. Import foreign schema

Database A is able to import the foreign schema from database B which means the connection from A to B is ok.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_foreign_table;
 ftrelid | ftserver |                    ftoptions
---------+----------+--------------------------------------------------
   42982 |    42980 | {schema_name=public,table_name=users}
   42985 |    42980 | {schema_name=public,table_name=items}
```

However, when I start making a query `SELECT * FROM users;` after the foreign schema import, the request just gets stuck without returning error or notifying a connection timeout. This is confusing as it's able to import the foreign schema from Database B, which should imply that the connection is ok.

Both of these databases are in the same availability zone and in their own security groups. I have also opened up all the inbound rules and outbound rules for both security groups the two databases are in.

Comment: How do you know there is a problem?  Maybe it is just taking a long time.  How big is the "users" table?  How long have you waited?  How long do you think it should take?